# Swift - How to implement a login/session (no code)

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift, authentication

My application has a login page and i would like to keep the user logged-in when he closes the app. Also, i have a logout button which should log-out the user and display the login page (even when he closes the app).

I tried to implement this using core data, but I have some issues with that and i'm not sure that is the best way to do it.

Can someone please give me some advices? I don't need code but just some idea of how i can implement that please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it as simple or complicated as you like. As simple as a Bool value in NSUserDefaults would do it. You could persist state in CoreData, Filesystem, NSUserDefaults. We store login credentials securely in the KeyChain.

For the authenticated areas of the app, check the state you have persisted on next app launch.

On logout, remove the state you have stored.

Comment: good ideas, I was actually thinking to use NSUserDefaults. Thank you!!